# How can i upload a file to google storage with customize filename in springboot？

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

In the demo, i try these code：

```
@Value("gs://${gcs-resource-test-bucket}/testgcs.txt")
private Resource gcsFile;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload")
public String writeGcs() throws IOException {
    String data = "test";

    try (OutputStream os = ((WritableResource) this.gcsFile).getOutputStream()) {
        os.write(data.getBytes());
    }
    return "file was updated\n";
}
```

These code can upload a file named as "testgce.txt" into my bucket, but how can i customize the filename in code?
I want a method like

```
public String writeGcs(String filename){
    String url = "gs://${gcs-resource-test-bucket}/"+filename;
}
```

How can i get the Resource Object by the url?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your Resource with Spring helper function

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

...

Resource r = resourceLoader.getResource("gs://........");
```